# Emailing Yii project via gmail

Tags: email, yii

Has anyone ever managed to email a Yii project (zipped) via gmail or any email client. Gmail keeps picking up an "executable file" whenever I try to email the zipped folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use password protected archive, to prevent scanning content of your archive by google.

Also you ca try to delete 'yiic' and 'yiic.bat' files from '/framework' directory

Answer (score 0):

Use `Google Drive`, the best & free way to transfer upto 10GB of data.
You can learn more about it at:
[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive)

Comment: thanks @PeterM for correction! added an extra space by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just change extension to something else, for instance project.zip into project.dat

Answer (score 0):

The executable file is yiic.bat. just delete yiic.bat file and mail...
install project without yiic.bat file by yiic file as

```
php yiic.php webapp appName
```